# Linking UI elements to IBOutlet after renaming file

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

So, I created a Single View Application in Xcode and added some UI elements. After this I created a UITabBarController and created three tabs. After this, the UI elements didn't work anymore, instead of filled circles, it only showed empty circles.

I read somewhere that this was because the ViewController class had a different name than the title of the ViewController in `.storyboard` file, however this is not the case (see picture).

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be because the class of your ViewController in your storyboard is different than the class name in the swift file. When you are in the storyboard, on the right panel, click the third icon from the left. What is the value of "Custom Class" and "Module" ?

If "Custom Class" is not exactly `Buttons` it will be broken

Comment: That was it. But what is the difference between `Class` and `Title` in regards to the ViewController (or any other UI element)?

Comment: I think "Title" is just an auto-generated XCode property and it does not have any effect on the code. "Class" however is what your program will use to determine which object the view controller is. Since this happens at runtime, you will never see an XCode error if you don't do it properly, you will only see crashes. You always need to set it for XCode to link the storyboard with your custom class.

Thanks for accepting my answer, I am glad that helped you :)